# Java create a brush stroke action

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, graphics, shapes

When you draw a freehand line with any paint application with whatever brush it ends up stacking together multiple points of that brush to form a brush stroke.

For example a basic pen stroke would stack up 1 pixel as you drag the mouse.
In more advanced applications you have a brush which is just a fancy Shape, say: a star for example, and stroking the canvas with the "star brush" would just cause the paint application to draw multiple stars as you drag your mouse over the canvas.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I already have implemented the "brush" ( i.e. a basic circle ) and whenever the user drags their mouse over the canvas while holding the left-mouse-button the application draws a circle for each new mouse position.

My problem is the "undo feature" if you may call it this way.

When I undo an action, my application only deletes the last Shape ( circle ) drawn, while I want it to delete the whole free-hand drawing ( collection of Shapes / circles ) from the user first press of the left-mouse-button to the release.

How do I "pack" a collection a Shape objects into one ?
A problem is also the repainting of all those circles, I want the repainting of maybe 30000 circles to be fast, just like a BufferedImage.

I already use a BufferedImage as the background of my image.

Every Shape that is "older" than 50 gets permanently stored in the BufferedImage background.

Currently I store the last 50 Shape objects in an ArrayList and the 51st ( the oldest ) gets permanently stored in the BufferedImage.
So the user can't undo 50 actions but rather 50 Shapes.

Thank You!

stripped down code sample:

```
public class GraphicPanel extends JComponent{

private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private int compXLen = 100;
private int compYLen = 100;
private boolean isCompFilled = false;
private boolean isAreaToBePainted = false;
private boolean isFocused = false;
private Shape ghost;
private ArrayList<Shape> shapeBuffer = new ArrayList<Shape>();
private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage( PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
private static final int PREF_W = 800;
private static final int PREF_H = 500;

@Override
public void paintComponent( Graphics gPlain ){
    super.repaint();
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gPlain;

    //paint background
    if (img != null){
      g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }       

    ghost = new Ellipse2D.Double( x-( compXLen/2 ), y-( compYLen/2 ), compXLen, compYLen );

    if( isAreaToBePainted ){
      //add ghost Shape to ArrayList
      add( g, ghost )
    }
    //paint arrayList
    for( Shape s : shapeBuffer ){
        g.fill( s );    
    }

    if( isFocused ){
    // draw ghost shape
       g.draw( ghost );
    }

}

/**
 * adds circles to arrayList
 */
private void add( Graphics2D g, Shape s ){
//fetch last arrayList element in Shape shp
//add ghost shape at the top of arrayList

    Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
    shapeBuffer.add( shp );
    g2.fill( shp );
    g2.dispose();
}

public void clearArea(){
    shapeBuffer = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    img = new BufferedImage( PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
    repaint();
}

private class GraphicPanelMouseListen implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    /**
     * @param e Mouse Event
     * @since 0.1
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ){}
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        isAreaToBePainted = true;
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ){}
    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ){
        isFocused = true;
    }
    public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ){
        isFocused = false;
         repaint();
    }
    public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e ){
        isAreaToBePainted = true;
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ){
      x = e.getX();
      y = e.getY();
      repaint();
            }

}//public class GraphicPanelMouseListen implements MouseListener

}//public class GraphicPanel
```

Comment: can we see the code that you have, and is causing the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using these lists altogether by storing every finished brush stroke, or any action for that matter, in its own image. You can then layer these in order they were made. It will be fewer of them, you can easily define how many actions in past you want to have while the bottom most one containing everything that didn't fit in the history.

Pixel blit is relatively fast operation, unlike stuff you do with shapes, and you can easily make it faster by using [VolatileImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html) instead of buffered image for collecting all actions in history.

In my opinion is this approach much faster, and less restricting for actions added in the future. You can easily just mark certain layers as invisible and move back and forth through history like in Photoshop for instance, but without any dependency on actual contents of said layers.